# SQL Code to eliminate text qualifiers from txt files

Tags: sql, csv, mysql-workbench

*Searched existing threads, no answer*

I am pulling data from a table and exporting to a CSV file using MYSQLWorkbench (only program compatible with our data system).  I have data that looks like the following:

| Item Number | Item Desc |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | HDW Cell |
| 105682 | Water Tube |

After I export this result to CSV, I then open/save it with notepad as a txt file.  I have to send this data to a vendor performing inventory for our stores, but the txt file looks as follows:

```
Item Number, Item Desc
"      10","HDW Cell"
"105682","Water Tube"
```

I need to eliminate the double quotes from the column data somehow, but I cannot change the export file type, and do not want to add a step in the CSV or TXT files to find/replace the quotes.  It also looks like the first text column is adding spaces in front of the 10 to preserve the total number of characters in that column - I need to get rid of this as well.  I need the output data to look like.

```
Item Number, Item Desc
10,HDW Cell
105682,Water Tube
```

I am currently using a simple select statement to pull the columns.  For background, this data can have as many as 200,000 + records, so I would like to accomplish as much as I can within the query before exporting the data to CSV.  I would be open to taking the original TXT file and using separate code to remove the text qualifiers.

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual type and version of the database? And what is the data type defined on the `Item Number` column?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to determine that, but it would appear that my database version is 5.1.61-log.  The item number can be treated as text for the exercise we are doing.

Comment: That sounds like MySQL, in which case it is waaaay out of date. So old it doesn't even qualify as a modern database engine. MySql stagnated and fell behind other platforms for about a decade starting with version 5.7 (3 years newer even than what you have). It's finally starting to catch up again, but 5.1 is crazy old, and probably **not safe** from an infosec standpoint.

Comment: Yes, all of that tracks.  It is the only 'supported' data access method to our ERP using SQL as our ERP provider is fairly antiquated.